# windows version : how to zoom using 2 finger pinch?

Tags: customization

In mac version of Blender , i can zoom the 3d space using 2 finger pinch (on trackpad). in windows version , does anyone know any setting, where i can zoom using 2 finger just like in mac version. If not , then is there any good reason why this feature is not available in windows version ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know a good reason but I also doesn't work on a touch screen

Comment: @BastianSpringer , thanks , i need it when i'm away from my desk. So i can work on couch with any 2 in 1 - convertible laptop or tablet like surface pro +stylus etc. So far the best thing i can use is 'tablet pro' app : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD3OWqfKtHQ

Comment: I understand your point - I just wanted to extend it. For now at least, you need to use the zoom button in the top right AFAIK

Comment: @BastianSpringer, yes thanks. I've just found out in windows version that None of all the 'trackpad' input in the preferences works. Seems that the tablet API has issue in windows version.